# React-Redux: Too many re-renders

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, reducers

In my react/redux app i'm trying to have the **AddBoxIcon** pop up a `Modal` whenever its clicked. At the moment i'm getting an error

> Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

2nd problem, I suspect the way i have configured the **toggleModal** action could be wrong.

My way is not working.

```
// Toggle Modal action
export const toggleModal = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: TOGGLE_MODAL,
  });
};

// Invoice Reducer
const initialState = {
  invoiceData: [],
  newInvoiceModal: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_MODAL:
      return {
        ...state,
        newInvoiceModal: !state.newInvoiceModal
      };

    case GET_INVOICE_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        invoiceData: action.payload,
      };

    case ADD_INVOICE_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        invoiceData: action.payload,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Invoice table** component

```
import AddInvoiceModal from './AddInvoiceModal'
import { getInvoiceData, toggleModal } from "../../actions/customers/invoice";

const InvoiceTable = (props) => {
  const invoiceData = useSelector((state) => state.invoice.invoiceData);
  const newInvoiceModal = useSelector((state) => state.invoice.newInvoiceModal);  
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); 

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getInvoiceData());
  }, [dispatch]);
  

  const classes = useStyles();

  const columns = [
    { name: "date", label: "Date" },
    { name: "invoiceOwner", label: "Name" },
    { name: "invoiceNo", label: "Invoice No" },
    { name: "product", label: "Product" },
  ];

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>

      {/* ADD NEW EMPLOYEE MODAL */}
      <AddInvoiceModal 
        toggleModal={dispatch(toggleModal())} 
        newInvoiceModal={newInvoiceModal} 
      />

      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>
            <MUIDataTable
              title={
                <Fragment>
                  Purchase Invoice
                  <Tooltip title="Add">
                    <AddBoxIcon          <===== ADD ICON
                      color="action"
                      style={addIcon}
                      onClick={dispatch(toggleModal())}  <===== MODAL TRIGGER
                    />
                  </Tooltip>
                </Fragment>
              }
              data={invoiceData}
              columns={columns}
              options={options}
            />
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

InvoiceTable.propTypes = {
  invoiceData: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  getInvoiceData: PropTypes.func,
  toggleModal: PropTypes.func,
  newInvoiceModal: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default InvoiceTable;
```

**Modal** file

```
const AddInvoiceModal = (props) => {
    return (
      <div className="App container">
        <Modal isOpen={props.newInvoiceModal} scrollable={true}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={props.toggleModal}>Add Invoice</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <h2>Hello</h2>
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button
              color="primary"
            >
            Submit
            </Button>{" "}
            <Button
              color="secondary"
            >
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );

}

export default AddInvoiceModal;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly I think the only issue is that this

```
toggleModal={dispatch(toggleModal())}
```

needs to be

```
toggleModal={() => dispatch(toggleModal())}
```

right now every render will call `dispatch(toggleModal())` which will cause a re-render which will call it again